# Server certificate was missing commonName attribute in subject name

Tags: ssl, svn

I'm trying to setup an SSL SVN server and when I try to checkout remotely I get the error `Server certificate 
was missing commonName attribute in subject name`

I did some googling and from what I can tell I need to add the IP address of the URL I'm accessing to `openss.cnf` with the `commonName` attribute like below.  I did that but I still get the error.

```
commonName                      = xx.xxx.xx.xx
commonName_max                  = 64
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like a CommonName mismatch with the SSL certificate.  Does the CN in your SSL certificate match your server?

You can run the following to view the SSL certificate:

`openssl x509 -noout -text -in ssl.crt`

**Edit**

To generate a snake oil cert, first generate the key:

`openssl genrsa -out host.key 1024`

Now generate the certificate:

`openssl req -new -key host.key -x509 -days 3650 -out host.crt`

openssl will prompt you for the information:

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:
Locality Name (eg, city) []:
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []:
Email Address []:
```

*Common Name* is where you specify your server's hostname.

Comment: I don't see "CN" in there anywhere... perhaps that's the problem?  It's not an official SSL, just something I generated on the server.

Comment: Check out my edit, that may be the issue.

Comment: Can I just modify the certificate now to include a common name rather than re-generate it?

Comment: That's not possible.